# Vertical Navbar and right side data

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am inserting a vertical menu bar and i want the data should come on the right.
I have a vertical menu bar on the left with many links. Each link is a different page. I want, when i click on the corresponding link it should show the corresponding page with menu bar on the left and the respective page data on the right. How can this be achieved.

Regards,
Abhay Varma

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I am keeping vertical menu bar in one file and then including this file in other files. But the problem is the data is not coming on right it is coming below of the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a simple HTML page. You need to create multiple pages with same sidebar and content. Just change the contend on each page and keep the left sidebar the same.

Comment: I think I shouldn't. It is something that you should learn. It is extremely basic. However if you can come up with some code then i can help :)